# Proving symmetric matrix has positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Let $A$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrix such that $A^2-5A+6Id_n = 0$
>
> where $Id_n $ stands for the identity matrix.
>
> Show that $A$ has only positive eigenvalues.

I know what eigenvalues are, what a symmetric matrix is, and everything else in the problem. I'm just pretty confused on how to start this proof/what it would look like. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

Let $v$ be an eigenvector,

$$A^2v-5Av + 6v = 0$$

Hence

$$(\lambda^2-5\lambda+6)v=0$$

Can you solve for $\lambda$?

Comment: I would probably emphasize that a symmetric matrix has a full collection of genuine real eigenvalues, and a basis of eigenvectors

Comment: wow that's such a clever and quick trick to do that. So I'd factor it to (λ-3)(λ-2), so both eigenvalues are positive. I love that

Comment: @Anthony That trick is explained through the Cayley Hamilton theorem. In short that theorem states that a matrix satisfies its own Characteristic Equation. You can look up on Wikipedia.